# "Error: Implicit function declaration" for one function but another in the same header file

Tags: c++, c

I want to use two functions `func1` and `func2` from the following C++ header file in a `xyz.c` file. I included the C++ header file in `xyz.c` (C file). `func1` appears before `func2` in `xyz.c`, but/and the complier only complains about `func2` by saying "Error: Implicit function declaration". Is there anything wrong with the C++ header file?

```
// C++ header file

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int func1(...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus

#includ <string.h>

extern "C"
int func2(...);

#endif
```

Comment: `__cpluscplus` is a typo, it will never be defined. Hence, the function is never declared.

Comment: Do you mean that the typo wasn't part of your actual code and you're still getting the error when you fix it?

Comment: yes, and I "didn't need to" fix anything in the actual code. `__cpluscplus` is a typo I made here but not in the actual code

Comment: It seems fine otherwise. I just tried including this header and calling these functions in a random C++ file and it only gave a linker error, which is understandable because I didn't actually define the functions. Could you perhaps post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you try to call the functions in a C++ file and it produces the error you're asking about? Also, are you using these in a C file or a C++ file, because if you are using a C file then `func2` will not be declared since it is in the `#if`.

Comment: I'm using these two functions in a C file. Could you explain more about why `func2` will not be declared in this case?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? It's inside of an `#ifdef` with the false condition.

Comment: Since `int func2(...);` is also in the `#ifdef __cplusplus` block, if the code is C and not C++ then all of `extern "C" int func2(...);` will be removed from your code in the preprocessor stage, so before your code is even compiled. HolyBlackCat gives the solution to this however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `__cplusplus` **is** defined, your header becomes:

```
extern "C"
{
    int func1(...);
};

extern "C"
int func2(...);
```

So far so good. If it's **not** defined, it becomes:

```
int func1(...);
```

The minimal fix is:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
int func2(...);
```

The **proper** fix is to have following at the beginning of the header, once:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

And this at the end:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then just declare your functions as:

```
int func1(...);
int func2(...);
```